# Jquery ui loading page into div without refresh

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I have menu with links and want to load `.php` pages into div with an id of `main` using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#documents").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#main").load(url);
    });
});
```

My HTML code is:

```
 <a class="button" id="documents" href="test.php">Test</a>
        <div>
            <br clear="all" />
        </div>
 <a class="button" id="documents" href="add.php">Add</a>
 <div>
            <br clear="all" />
        </div>
 <a class="button" id="documents" href="view.php">View</a>
```

I want to load in this div:

```
<div id="main">
</div>
```

The problem is only the first link works and the other links are not loaded into the div. They go directly into the url. Please help and suggest. I am new in Jquery UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take `documents` as `class` not `id`. because `ID` is unique for page.

```
<a class="button documents" href="test.php">Test</a>
        <div>
            <br clear="all" />
        </div>
 <a class="button documents" href="add.php">Add</a>
 <div>
            <br clear="all" />
        </div>
 <a class="button documents" href="view.php">View</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".documents").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#main").load(url);
    });
```

Comment: @Saikhasan just figured out that it goes like class="button documents". Thanks.